# Pandas: Selecting rows by list

Tags: pandas, sum

I tried following code to select columns from a dataframe. My dataframe has about 50 values. At the end, I want to create the sum of selected columns, create a new column with these sum values and then delete the selected columns.

I started with

```
columns_selected = ['A','B','C','D','E']
df = df[df.column.isin(columns_selected)]
```

but it said AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'

Regarding the sum: As I don't want to write for the sum

```
df['sum_1'] = df['A']+df['B']+df['C']+df['D']+df['E']
```

I also thought that something like

```
 df['sum_1'] = df[columns_selected].sum(axis=1)
```

would be more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `df[columns_selected]` to sub-select the df by a list of columns

you can then do `df['sum_1'] = df[columns_selected].sum(axis=1)`

To filter the df to just the cols of interest pass a list of the columns, `df = df[columns_selected]` note that it's a common error to just a list of strings: `df = df['a','b','c']` which will raise a `KeyError`.

Note that you had a typo in your original attempt:

```
df = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(columns_selected)]
```

The above would've worked, firstly you needed `columns` not `column`, secondly you can use the boolean mask as a mask against the columns by passing to `loc` or `ix` as the column selection arg:

```
In [49]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=list('abcde'))
df

Out[49]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -0.778207  0.480142  0.537778 -1.889803 -0.851594
1  2.095032  1.121238  1.076626 -0.476918 -0.282883
2  0.974032  0.595543 -0.628023  0.491030  0.171819
3  0.983545 -0.870126  1.100803  0.139678  0.919193
4 -1.854717 -2.151808  1.124028  0.581945 -0.412732

In [50]:
cols = ['a','b','c']
df.ix[:, df.columns.isin(cols)]

Out[50]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.778207  0.480142  0.537778
1  2.095032  1.121238  1.076626
2  0.974032  0.595543 -0.628023
3  0.983545 -0.870126  1.100803
4 -1.854717 -2.151808  1.124028
```

Comment: Okay, first part works. How about dropping columns_selected after that?

Comment: You mean just `df = df[columns_selected]`?

Comment: Yes, after creating the colum of the .sum(axis=1), I want to remove all columns_selected